# App review cancelled but IAP still waiting for review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, release

I submitted an IPA and two IAPs for review, but had to cancel the review after 18 hours because of missing data. Now the app is in the state "prepare for submission", but the IAPs are still "waiting for review".

When I try to submit a new binary the option to add IAPs is gone.

Before uploading the IAPs there were a IAP section here

[image]

but now it's gone

[image]

The IAPs have the status `waiting for review` in the IAP section

[image]

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Should I want for the IAPs to finish?  
Should I the new binary and the IAPs will be adde to it automatically?
Should I delete the IAPs and create new ones?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to upload the new IPA without adding the IAPs to the new submission.
I wrote a short explanation in the review details along the lines of

> I added the two IAP subscriptions related to this submission in the last review and they are still in review event though I closed the review.
> I hope that they will be automatically linked or that you could like them for me.

The review passed and now both the IAPs and the App is ready for release.